# Not able to disconnect form SSID in ios React native - react-native-wifi-reborn

Tags: ios, react-native, wifi

```
await WifiManager.disconnectFromSSID(currentSSID)
.then(
() => console.log('success disconnect'),
e => {
console.log('failure disconnect', e);
},
)
.catch(e => {
console.log('error', e);
});
```

even for the wrong SSID, I'm getting disconnection successful.

I'm trying to implement a connection to an already connected wifi SSID in order to check the password is correct. that too is getting successes for the wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem where I'm trying to verify a WiFi password based on it's SSID.

This function uses the iOS network command `removeConfigurationForSSID` which only disconnects from networks that have been configured within the same app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866727-removeconfigurationforssid